# PHP functions added since version

Tags: php

Is there a resource that allows me to see the PHP functions added/changed since a certain version release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the PHP Change Logs?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/doc.changelog.php

Take your pick at the list of changes you want to see - its all there... Just click around...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php

Comment: Sort of, I was hoping there'd be a more ordered one, for example, where it could say "these were added, these were modified".

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.functions.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.functions.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.functions.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.functions.php